# CiviSMS merge option prior to sending?

Tags: civisms, duplicate-contacts

When exporting search results or preparing a New Mailing in Civi Mail, there is an option to merge contacts from the same household/address (export) or remove duplicate emails (CiviMail).

1. Does a similar merging option exist for a New SMS in CiviSMS?
2. If not, what is best practice for preventing multiple SMS going to duplicate phone numbers?

Backstory: Our organization has a large number of families, so parents will often register their children with the parent's mobile number.  Thus the high probability of duplicate mobile numbers for mass SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It appears there isn't a merge option for SMS.
2. At present, I am exporting my search results and/or group, finding/removing the duplicate mobile phone numbers in Excel (via Conditional Formatting), and re-importing the remaining contacts and numbers as a new group that I can then target for the New SMS.

I don't know of a purely Civi way of doing this, but if someone has other ideas, I'd love to hear them.